# IIS website needing permissions to modify own folder

Tags: iis

I have a website I am setting up which creates a subfolder to its own location based on which user logs into the website.  An administrative account we'll call *admin* runs the website through IIS Manager (as indicated through the basic and advanced settings on the site's tab in IIS, which indicate the credentials for *admin* are correct), and *admin* also has full security permissions to the folder that IIS refers to.  The website is I think otherwise fully up and running because the login screen loads successfully.  However, despite the fact that *admin* is both running the site and has full access to the folder, it is failing to create the folder and as such is failing to operate the website properly.  I know it is this error because the website's error logging reports an `UnauthorizedAccessException` to the folder I would expect to be created.

Can anyone help me figure out why it is unable to create a folder in the website location?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To fix issue, you can try to add the IIS AppPool user to the root folder of your application by right clicking the folder and selecting Properties. Select the Security tab and add the IIS AppPool<AppPoolName> user.

And you can also decide to create a custom user to access the file system from IIS. Create a new Windows (or AD) user and click your site inside the IIS Manager. From the Actions window click Basic Settings. Finally, click the Connect as button and input the new user below Specific user:

[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the App Pool had different users from the website's.  I was looking in the Basic Settings and saw I had it running as the admin user but in its Application Pool Advanced Settings I edited the Process Model Identity to the same user as well and it started working.  I'm not 100% sure that's what you said to do?  I'm a little out of my depth here.  But what you said led me there eventually by talking about the AppPool so thank you very much!